# MDX Calculation to work on all dim attributes

Tags: ssas, mdx

This calc works fine for grade code in the grade dimension

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Daily Headcount Percentage by Grade]
AS [Measures].[Headcount]
/
([Grade].[Grade Code].[All], [Measures].[Headcount]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"
```

I'd like for the calc to work against any of the attributes in the grade dim as currently all but grade code returns 100%?

Answer (score 0):

A quick test on a local cube, removing the attribute worked for me does it work for you?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Daily Headcount Percentage by Grade]
AS [Measures].[Headcount]
/
([Grade].[All], [Measures].[Headcount]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"
```

Comment: A little closer, it now works for the three members in the single user-defined hierarchy in this dim but not for attribute hierarchies

Comment: @DingoCC I'm not following you, could you give an example of where it fails?

Comment: Sure @Meff, I could be wrong here but I think your suggestion worked because there is one and only one user defined hierarchy so the calc is applied against it when the cube is processed.  The calc will also work for an attribute hierarchy such as shown above using [Grade].[Grade Code].[All] in the the denominator.  So is it correct then that a calculated measure must 'target' a particular hierarchy be it a user-defined hierarchy or attribute hierarchy?